# Angular JS return undefined response

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a http request and get the results which 
I am able to do in the browser with the following

```
http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/InteractiveChart/json?parameters={"Normalized":false,"NumberOfDays":5,"DataPeriod":"Day","Elements":[{"Symbol":"ACN","Type":"price","Params":["c"]}]}
```

But when I execute the following code the response returned is undefined.Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here

```
var test = JSON.stringify({"Normalized":false,
                           "NumberOfDays":5,
                           "DataPeriod":"Day",
                           "Elements":[{"Symbol":"ACN",
                            "Type":"price",
                            "Params":["c"]
                  }]
    });

console.log(test);
$http({
        url:"http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/InteractiveChart/json",
method : "GET",
parameters: test
    }).then(
        /* success */
        function(response) {
            var stock = {};
            stock = angular.fromJson(response);
            var Data = stock.Dates;
            console.log(Data);
            $scope.content = response.data;
            $scope.statuscode = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statustext;
            console.log('success');
        },
        /* failure */
        function(result) {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

Please guide me

Comment: why are you calling fromJson on your response?

Comment: Check your browser console to check error

Answer (score 0):

Your `Content-Type` in response header is not properly set.

Check whether `Content-Type` in response header is `application/json` or not.

Currently it look like this `Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=UTF-8`

So, your response is not recieved in JSON format.Check for proper JSON encoding

Comment: It is returning application/json response and when I inspect the response in the browser it is returning a message Failed parsing JSON input

Comment: You are sending  stringify JSON.Make sure you parsing it correctly

Comment: My JSON Object needs to be passed like this var param = "{'Normalized':false,'NumberOfDays':5,'DataPeriod':'Day','Elements':[{'Symbol':'ACN','Type':'price','Params':['c']}]}";  Concatenating the url with param works fine any ideas?